# how to play video with multiple time stamp from main video in android

Tags: android

```
private VideoView mVideoView;
    private boolean mShouldStop = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        mVideoView.setVideoPath("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.android.camera2video/files/a.mp4");
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.seekTo(6000);
        mVideoView.start();
        trackProgress();
    }

    private void trackProgress() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!mShouldStop) {
                    if (mVideoView != null && mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
                        if (mVideoView.getCurrentPosition() >= 12000) {
                            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                            mShouldStop = true;
                        }
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

This is my code for play video for on time stamp like if we have 15 min video then  suppose i have to play only for 5 to 6 min video then using given code i am able to play video from 5 to 6 min from main video . but i have to play video for multiple time stamp  from main video suppose i have time stamp [3-5,7-8,9-11,13-14] then it should play video from 3 to -5 minute video continue then 7 to 8 continue .... like that 13-14 video in single video i.e we have to merge video in Single video.

Comment: @kara4k hi is there any Solution for Question

Comment: @kara4k no still i dint get any Solution